# iOS web clip icon not showing up on local server

Tags: ios, icons, web-clips

We've made a web app with some optimisation for iOS's Web Clip feature. Obviously I've added some icons for the homescreen, but they fail to show up when the app is accessed on our local server. When I move all relevant files to a completely different server (i.e. our website hoster) they show up just fine. This leads me to conclude our server is at fault, but I can't imagine why. *Especially* since they do show up on iOS7 but not on iOS6.

Here's the index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "config.php";
require_once "functions.php";

if ($_GET['a'] == 'logout') {
    include 'logout.php';
}

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    include 'app.php';
} else {
    if ($_GET['access'] == "denied")
        echo "<div id='accessdenied'>Access Denied!</div>";
    include 'index.html';
}
?>
```

Here's the relevant code from index.html (not that this is at fault):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png" >
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" >
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" >
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" >
```

I've also concluded it's not due to the PHP including. A new project with HTML only on our local server raises the same problem.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to put the image in your "root" folder, that way worked for me... I am not sure why...its pretty weird I can't seem to get it work if I put the image file in other folders